# Orchard: what is currently the optimal method for password storage?

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords, orchardcms

I'm currently developing an Orchard CMS platform for one of our customers, a small club of about 400 members. After another customer recently had their website hacked and user data leaked (for the record: we didn't develop their website), we want to provide optimal security to our current and new clients. This does not mean the best security, we just want to make the site secure enough that whatever data can be found in the website isn't worth the effort the attacker has to do to get it. Since we only have a small member pool for this website, I doubt it's attractive to begin with, but considering the recent events, we can't be too sure.

One of the subjects we're studying is password storage. We don't want to skimp on this because this is a vital part of security. I've read up on SHA512, BCrypt and other hashing algorithms, but it's hard to form a clear overview of all the different algorithms and methods found online. The information is spread out across different sources, some of which can be found on MSDN, but some of which can only be found hidden in blog posts and comments.

What algorithms for hashing and salthashing passwords and other sensitive data are currently viewed as the best? And which ones are to be avoided like the plague?

Comment: Firstly, are you planning to write your own user section for Orchard? The built in membership uses SHA1 to hash passwords, I believe. Breaking SHA1 takes a while and costs a hell of a lot in computing power. I think you can safely assume no one is going to bother.

Comment: What we want is the following: 1) custom user fields (for stuff like company name, function, telephone, address,...); 2) event planning and user registration for events; 3) adding new content and events in a way even non-programmers can do. I'm not that worried about hash cracking, but more about the reverse: rainbow tables and brute forcing. Also, SHA-1 is being phased out in favor of SHA-2 and SHA-3 according to the articles I've read, because hardware is catching up to the point that bruteforcing is viable.

Comment: As a followup: SHA-1 is designed for quick encryption for stuff like SSL connections. It only does 1 pass for encryption. Because of this, calculating a large amount of hashes is incredibly fast. If possible, I'd prefer to use an algorithm which IS designed for password protection.

Comment: The hashing algorithm is saved along with the hash in the database. If you look at MembershipService.CreateUser you'll see the code that sets the algorithm. You can use a modified version of that code to create your own users with a different algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. that wasn't really my question though, I know how to change the algorithm. I'm wondering which algorithm I should use, since SHA-1 is far from the best for encrypting passwords.

Comment: This is a good answer on the subject: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/20774 - in short: use bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBKDF2/RFC2898/PKCS#5v2, BCrypt, and SCrypt are the current "good" ways to store passwords.  All other ways are bad as of early 2014.

Looking at [Orchard SetPassword](https://github.com/AzureWebSites/OrchardCMS/blob/master/Modules/Orchard.Users/Services/MembershipService.cs), it appears to be a single round of salted SHA-1.  This is pitiful!  See [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for the general treatise.

In your case, if you want to stick with pure .NET, I would say use the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is a PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 implementation, feed it a random per-user 16 byte salt generated by the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the same class Orchard uses to generate its salt), and as many iterations as you can use expect to be just below a CPU bound server at maximum expected load - that number should be in the tens of thousands.

Store the password hash, the plaintext (binary or hex string or Base64 string) salt, and the number of iterations in the database.  The number of itersations should be stored so you can easily increase security later.  If possible, also store a "Version" so that you can easily upgrade to a new algorithm later.